# Set Theory $M\setminus\emptyset$ possible?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

M is a non-empty set so is : $M\setminus\emptyset$  possible to create a set like that?

Comment: It is simply $$M \setminus \emptyset =M$$

Comment: thanks for the answer but why is it exactly the same ? i know it is a bit tautological

Comment: Given any two sets, $X$ and $Y$, $X\setminus Y$ is also a set.

Comment: Did you mean $M\backslash\{\emptyset\}$?

Answer (score 2):

We have $M \setminus \emptyset =M$.

Proof:

1. If $x \in M \setminus \emptyset$, then $x \in M$
2. If $x \in M$, then $x \in M$ and $x \notin \emptyset$, hence $x \in M \setminus \emptyset.$

Answer (score 1):

We know that,
$$A\B=A\cap B^c$$
$$\Longrightarrow M\setminus\emptyset=M\cap U=M$$
where $U$ is the universal set.

Hope it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

$X \setminus Y$ is the set of all elements in $X$ and not in $Y$ (i.e. $X \setminus Y = \{x \in X : x \not\in Y\}$). So if $X \cap Y = \emptyset$, then $X \setminus Y = X$. In your case, $M \cap \emptyset$ is really easy to observe. So you have $M \setminus \emptyset = M$.